# How to set a default value for a column in SQL Server when changing the column's data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to change the data type of a column from integer to datetime in an SQL Server database.
The column contains NULL values only.

This works:
`ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname DATETIME`

However this doesn't:
`ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname DATETIME DEFAULT NULL`

I would like to know why exactly this doesn't work.

I know that it is possible to add a default value with this command afterwards:

`ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT NULL FOR columnname`

But is there a way to change the data type and add a default value with just one command?

EDIT: I have to do this in a Sybase db as well and there it works like this:
`ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname DATETIME DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: You cannot alter a constraint you can only drop or add them.

Comment: @Stu I am not altering a constraint am I? Im altering the data type of a column for which no constraint exists.

Comment: The short answer is that syntax is not supported - you would also have to first drop a constraint if it did exist before changing the data type.

Comment: Note that it is not necessary to add an explicit default constraint of a NULL value since NULL is the default value anyway.

Comment: I'll add that you don't specify whether the column is nullable - meaning you rely on and assume a specific db/connection setting (ansi_null_dflt_on, ansi_null_default) that determines column nullability in the absence of the attribute.

Comment: The grammar does not allow altering a column and adding a constraint, you can only add a constraint inline at the same time as adding a new column https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16